# Can someone show me implentation look like this and similar to this ? css and jQuery effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i see a page http://input.mozilla.com/en-US/feedback#happy from mozilla and i found something special their.

page not refresh if back or forward press after fill form  and later page load.

they show them by animating. can someone show me the code look like that or similar with the example.

Comment: Your english is like a puzzle.

Comment: Right click -> View Page Source.... there is your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions) (for animating the dialogs etc.) and [history push / popstates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

See:

https://github.com/mozilla/input.mozilla.org/blob/master/media/js/feedback.js#L9

and

https://github.com/mozilla/input.mozilla.org/blob/master/media/css/feedback.css#L43

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the page (won't download the latest FF for it) but I'm guessing they are using history.pushState to manipulate your browser state and do ajax calls for loading pages if the browser supports history.pushState.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history